# Interesting behavior of $\frac{n}{v_2(n!)+1}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I've lately noticed some interesting behavior from the values of the function $f(n)=\frac{n}{v_2(n!)+1}$,
Where $v_p(n)$ is the $p$-adic valuation of $n$, and we also know that $v_p(n!)=\sum_{t=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^t} \right\rfloor$.
 I'll show the values of $f(n)$ for some values of $n$ below:
$(n,f(n))=(5,\frac{5}{4}),(10,\frac{10}{9}),(20,\frac{20}{19}),(30,\frac{10}{9}),(40,\frac{40}{39}),(50,\frac{25}{24}),(60,\frac{20}{19}),(100,\frac{50}{49}),...(900,\frac{300}{299}),(1000,\frac{200}{199})$

The first question that comes up is whether $f(n)>1$ for all $n>1$. To prove this, we need to prove $n>v_2(n!)+1$. 

The second question is whether all $f(n)$s are in the form of a super particular ratio$(\frac{a+1}{a})$ for all values of $n$. For this happening, we need $\frac{1}{f(n)-1}$ to be a natural number. After some calculations, we should get to prove $n-(v_2(n!)+1)|n$. This seems unlikely to be true for all $n$, but I would like knowing the values of $n$ for which it holds, as I don't have any idea to approach this problem!
 For the first problem i tried using the formula i mentioned earlier, and i got this:
$n>1+\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor+\lfloor{\frac{n}{2^2}}\rfloor+\lfloor{\frac{n}{2^3}}\rfloor+...$ But i don't know where to get from here, since we've got to deal with an infinite number of floors in the RHS!
I would appriecate any help :)
Edit: As Gerry Myerson pointed out, It seems that $f(p)$ for some prime numbers $p$ is in the form of $\frac{a+2}{a}$ instead. It would be nice to see for which prime numbers $p$ this happens, but still i have no idea in approaching this problems.

Comment: Check if $[n-(v_2(n!)+1)]\mid \color{Red}{n}$ is really what you want.

Comment: @Blue I double checked it, i think it's true!

Comment: $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{a+1}{a}\implies (x-y)\mid \color{Red}{y}$ not $(x-y)\mid x$.

Comment: It's not an infinite number of floors, since only finitely many are nonzero. Anyway, $\nu_2(n!)$ goes $0,1,1,3,3,4,4,7,7,8,\dots$ which I will type into the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences to see what comes up.... OK, it's https://oeis.org/A011371 where you'll find many formulas, inequalities, links, references, enoough to make you quite happy, I'm sure.

Comment: @blue if $x-y|y$ then $x-y|y+(x-y)$ so $x-y|x$ as well, which in my case is a lot easier.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you! I saw the inequality there, but unfortunately i couldn't find any proof for it! For that, i think what achille hui had answered is sufficient, but still i couldnt find anything about the second question there :(

Comment: Oops, that was embarassing.

Comment: I never suggested $f(p)$ is of the form $(a+2)/a$ for all prime numbers $p$. $f(5)=5/4$, $f(17)=17/16$, and you can look through the listing at the oeis link to get more counterexamples. Indeed, you should, before you make any more conjectures that can be easily shot down.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh sure, That was embarrassing :P

Answer (score 5):

For the first part of the question, there is a theorem by Legendre (1808).

> Let $p$ be a prime and let $n = a_k p^k + a_{k-1} p_{k-1} + \ldots + a_1 p + a_0$ be the
>   base-$p$ expansion of $n$, we have
>   $$v_p(n!) = \frac{n - (a_k + a_{k-1} + \ldots + a_1 + a_0)}{p-1}$$

Apply this to the case $p = 2$, we have $v_2(n!) = n - \alpha(n)$ where $\alpha(n)$ is the number of set bits in binary expansion of $n$. This implies $n \ge v_2(n!) + 1$ for all $n$.

For a proof of the theorem, see 
[this](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LegendresTheorem.shtml).

Comment: Thank you, but are you sure the question doesn't have a proof that is a little more elementary? Because i actually found the proof of Theorem (Legendre, 1808) a little long!

Comment: @CODE the proof looks long but it is elementary and straight forward. Essentially, what it does is break $n$ into sum of those $a_k p^k$ and ask what is the contribution of each piece to $v_p(n!)$. It turns out the piece $a_k p^k$ contributes $a_k (p^{k-1} + p^{k-2} + \cdots + 1) = a_k \frac{p^k - 1}{p-1}$. Re-express everything back into $n$ and $a_k$ gives you that formula.

Comment: Thank you for rephrasing it, now it is way more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

The first place that answers the second question is $n=7$, as $\nu_2(7!)=4$, and we get $f(7)=7/5$, which is not of the form $(a+1)/a$. $f(11)=11/9$, $f(13)=13/11$, $f(19)=19/17$, $f(21)=21/19$ (so it's not just primes), ..., $f(46)=46/43$ (so it's not just odd numbers), .... I'm not confident that there's a simple & useful characterization of the counterexamples.

Comment: And also as i have asked in the question itself, we still need to know for which values of $n$ we have $n-(v_2(n!)+1)|n$, or if we could have any method to approach this kind of problems at all!

Answer (score 1):

Well I myself came up with another proof for the second question, which i think is a little shorter (or more elementary) than what **achille hui** suggested using that theorem by Legendre. THe complete proof of mine is as following:
First, we will prove for each positive real number $x$, $2\lfloor x \rfloor \leq \lfloor 2x \rfloor$ (We call this Inequality **I**).
Assume $x=n+p$ for some integer $n$ and a real number $0\leq p<1$. Using this, we should prove $2\lfloor n+p \rfloor \leq \lfloor 2n+2p \rfloor$. by using basic floor function rules, we find out we should only prove  $2\lfloor p \rfloor \leq \lfloor 2p \rfloor$. Because $p<1$ and $p$ is positive, so our case is proven completely. Also, the LHS is always $0$ and the RHS is always positive, and the equality holds only when $2p<1$ which means $0\leq p<0.5$.
Now, we first define $S=v_2(n!)=\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor+\lfloor{\frac{n}{2^2}}\rfloor+\lfloor{\frac{n}{2^3}}\rfloor+...$ By using Inequality **I**, we can say:
$2\lfloor \frac{n}{2^i} \rfloor \leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2^{i-1}} \rfloor$ . Using this several times, we can say $2(\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor+\lfloor{\frac{n}{2^2}}\rfloor+\lfloor{\frac{n}{2^3}}\rfloor+...)\leq \lfloor n \rfloor +\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor+\lfloor{\frac{n}{2^2}}\rfloor+\lfloor{\frac{n}{2^3}}\rfloor+...$ and  $\lfloor n \rfloor = n$ so $2S\leq S+n$ which means $S\leq n$. Now we show that the LHS of on of the inequalities can be made larger in number by one, which in result makes $S+1\leq n$ which is the desired inequality.
 We know that every natural number $n$ is between two powers of $2$, say $2^k\leq n<2^{k+1}$. By using $2\lfloor \frac{n}{2^i} \rfloor \leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2^{i-1}} \rfloor$ for case $i=k+1$ (which indeed is included in the sum) we have: $2\lfloor \frac{n}{2^{k+1}} \rfloor \leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2^{k}} \rfloor$ and also we have $2^k\leq n<2^{k+1}$ we have $1\leq \frac{n}{2^{k}} < 2$ and $\frac{n}{2^{k+1}}<1$. This means the RHS in the inequality is $1$ but the LHS is $0$. So we may assume the LHS in there inequality is exactly $1$ instead of $0$, because we already have the exact value of it in the RHS and we want to make the inequality stronger, which proves our result ($S+1\leq n$).